# Recurrence with Google calendar ruby API V3

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-calendar-api

Using the following code, I've not been able to push any recurring events to google calendar. However, take off the 'recurrence' item from event and it works.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
  event = {
    'summary' => 'Appointment',
    'location' => 'Somewhere',
    'start' => {
       'dateTime' => '2011-06-03T10:00:00.000-07:00'
    },
    'end' => {
       'dateTime' => '2011-06-03T10:25:00.000-07:00'
    },
    'recurrence' => [
      "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=5"
    ]
  }

  result = @client.execute(:api_method => @service.events.insert,
                  :parameters => {'calendarId' => 'hg9a7o16bm6dj0tmuo481499mc@group.calendar.google.com'},
                  :body_object => event,
                  :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
  puts result.data.id.to_s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timezone needs to be set in a seperate field as this

```
event = {
  'summary' => 'Appointment',
  'location' => 'Somewhere',
  'start' => {
     'dateTime' => '2011-06-03T10:00:00.000-07:00',
     'timeZone' => 'America/Montreal'
  },
  'end' => {
     'dateTime' => '2011-06-03T10:25:00.000-07:00',
     'timeZone' => 'America/Montreal'
  },
  'recurrence' => [
    "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=5"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20120701T160000Z";

Comment: That was not the problem. It was only a timezone problem .. as indicated on the api  developpers guide -_-'. I'm feeling stupid

Comment: Don't worry, we've all been there (more often than I'd care to admit).